# Trouble with reqwest: Unable to deserialize JSON response + `match` issues

Tags: rust, serde, reqwest

I am learning Rust and it's web api support. I am working on a simple project which does a web API call. Here's the intuition:

(It's all about getting Sprint dates from an Azure DevOps project)

1. In `src/getlatestsprint.rs` I have a struct that has fields called "date" and "sprint". They're both String type.

```
pub struct Sprint {
    date: String,
    sprint: String,
}
```

2. I am then doing an `impl` on it and I am expecting it to return the Sprint itself, and it's supposed to have the `date` and the `sprint` number. FYI, what it is returning in the code is just placeholder.
3. The trouble I am having is with the response (not this block).

```
impl Sprint {

    pub fn get_sprint_and_date() -> Result<Sprint, reqwest::Error> {
        
        let sprint_url: &str = "https://dev.azure.com/redactedOrg/redactedProj/redactedTeam/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0";

        let pat: &str = "redactedPAT";

        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

        let get_request = client.get(sprint_url)

                                    .basic_auth(&"None", Some(pat))
                                    .send()?;
```

4. All this works. `get_request.status()` is `200` and `get_request.text()` is `Ok(JSON_respose)`. The trouble starts from here:

```
                if get_request.status() == 200 {
            match get_request.text() {
                Ok(v) => {
                    let deserialized_json: HashMap<String, serde_json::Value> = serde_json::from_str(&v).unwrap(); //This I got from another SO post that I was going through to work this out.

                    match deserialized_json.get("value") {
                        Some(des_j) => des_j,
                        None => None, //It says here "expected `&serde_json::Value`, found enum `std::option::Option`" This is where I am lost really.
                    }
                },
                _ => (),
            }
        }


//Placeholder return statement (I know I don't need to write return, but I am just doing it because I am used to it in other languages)
        return Ok(Sprint {
            date: String::from("sdfsd"),
            sprint: String::from("dsfsfsdfsdfsd"),
        })
    }
}
```

My intention is to return the latest date and sprint got from the response as a Struct.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
Sample JSON response:

```
{ 
    "count": 82, 
    "value": [
        { 
            "id": "redactedID", 
            "name": "Sprint 74", 
            "path": "redactedProjectName\\Sprint 74", 
            "attributes": { 
                "startDate": "2018-10-22T00:00:00Z", 
                "finishDate": "2018-11-04T00:00:00Z", 
                "timeFrame": "past"
            }, 
            "url": "dev.azure.com/redactedOrg/redactedProject/redactedProj/_apis/…"
        } 
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I managed to get what I wanted. I wasn't aware that to work with nested JSON, I had to create a Struct for each of the nested keys. Not just that, I had to even match the case of the field that I am getting the response of. Weird, but OK. I am pretty sure there's an easier way ti do this, but I was able to resolve it myself.

Here are the Structs that I created.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Response {
    count: u32,
    value: Vec<Value>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
struct Value {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    path: String,
    attributes: Attributes,
    url: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
struct Attributes {
    startDate: String,
    finishDate: String,
    timeFrame: String,
}
```

Comment: Check out my comment on your question to clean this up even more. Good job though, take an upvote for figuring it out mostly on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

We can serialize and deserialize directly to a custom struct using serde.
Let's start by deriving `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for `Sprint`:

```
//This requires the serde crate with derive feature
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Sprint {
    date: String,
    sprint: String,
}
```

Then we can clean up the implementation:

```
impl Sprint {

    pub fn get_sprint_and_date() -> Result<Sprint, reqwest::Error> {
    
        let sprint_url: &str = "https://dev.azure.com/redactedOrg/redactedProj/redactedTeam/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.0";

        let pat: &str = "redactedPAT";

        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

        let get_request = client.get(sprint_url)
                                .basic_auth(&"None", Some(pat))
                                .send()?;
        //This requires the reqwest crate with the json feature
        let sprint: Sprint = get_request.json()?;
        
        Ok(sprint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. This is what I get when I do exactly this way 

`Err(reqwest::Error { kind: Decode, source: Error("missing field `date`", line: 1, column: 31215) })`

What should I be aware of before doing this? I should say I get a nested JSON as response. It's not flat JSON, so, i don't think putting them into the `sprint` Struct as you suggested would work? I could be wrong though.

Comment: Could you give an example of your expected json? It seems like your server response doesn't contain date as a top level field.

Comment: That's correct. The response does not contain `date` as the top level field. It contains `count` and `value`. Does that mean I'd have to change the names of the Stuct fields to that? Then what about the nested JSON data inside of the field? Like, `value` has the actual data that I am interested it. How's that going to be interpreted? My trouble lies because I am comparing all this to how Python's `Request` module functions, which is normal I guess, as I am more used to that.

Comment: Example:

```
{
    "count": 82,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "redactedID",
            "name": "Sprint 74",
            "path": "redactedProjectName\\Sprint 74",
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2018-10-22T00:00:00Z",
                "finishDate": "2018-11-04T00:00:00Z",
                "timeFrame": "past"
            },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/redactedOrg/redactedProject/redactedProj/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/redactedIDofSomethingIDoNotKnow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Just image more records under `value`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I managed to resolve it.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson, You can de-structure the nested json by using [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.72/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) to navigate to the json entry you'd like, then deserialize to a concrete struct. So you can get away with only the `Sprint` struct, but you'd have to navigate to the inner json object whose only values are a `String` and a `Date`, then deserialize to `Sprint`. Also check out [serde's field attributes](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) if you'd like json field names to potentially differ from struct field names.